# How do I encode a Dart string in base64?

Tags: dart

I'm working with an API that requires data encoded in base64. How can I encode a simple string in base64?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It requires a few steps, but encoding a string in base64 is pretty straightforward.

Dart has a function in the [package:crypto](http://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/crypto/0.9.0/index.html#crypto/crypto.CryptoUtils@id_bytesToBase64) library, `CryptoUtils.bytesToBase64`, which takes a list of bytes to encode as base64. In order to get the list of bytes from a Dart string, you can use the `UTF8.encode()` function in the [dart:convert](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:convert.Utf8Codec#id_encode) library.

All together, this looks like:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';

main() {
  var str = "Hello world";
  var bytes = UTF8.encode(str);
  var base64 = CryptoUtils.bytesToBase64(bytes);
  print(base64);
}
```

---

If you're working inside the browser, then you have the easier option of using the browser's built in `btoa` function. The above code snippet becomes:

```dart
import 'dart:html';

main() {
  var str = "Hello world";
  var base64 = window.btoa(str);
  print(base64);
}
```

Comment: As of 0.9.2 of the `crypto` package, `CryptoUtils` is deprecated. Use instead `BASE64` from the `dart:convert` package.

Comment: Yes, this has been made much easier with BASE64 in dart:convert. Please consider marking Ben's answer as accepted instead of this one.

Answer (score 114):

There is no need to use the crypto package since the core libraries provide built-in support for base64 encoding and decoding.

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-convert/dart-convert-library.html

```
import 'dart:convert';

main() {
  final str = "Hello world";
  final bytes = utf8.encode(str);
  final base64Str = base64.encode(bytes);
  print(base64Str);
}
```