# Convert JavaScript function to Dart: Word of safety

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

Is it possible to perform the same JavaScript function in Dart?
I was looking at the add-ons and found a complement that is close to what I am trying to do.

The complement found was:
https://pub.dev/packages/js_shims

You can read more here.
[Documentation: JS_SHIMS](https://pub.dev/documentation/js_shims/latest/js_shims/charCodeAt.html)

The function must return the encrypted password. For example:

**Password**: pass1234

In javascript the encrypted password returns me to: **cGFzczEyMzQ=**

**My function JS DEMO:**

```js
var ezEncodeChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

function ezEncode(){
  var str = document.getElementById('txtPassword').value; 
  var out, i, len;
  var c1, c2, c3;

  len = str.length;
  i = 0;
  out = "";
  while(i < len)
 {
  c1 = str.charCodeAt(i++) & 0xff;
  if(i == len)
  {
   out += ezEncodeChars.charAt(c1 >> 2);
    out += ezEncodeChars.charAt((c1 & 0x3) << 4);
    out += "==";
    break;
  }
  c2 = str.charCodeAt(i++);
  if(i == len)
  {
     out += ezEncodeChars.charAt(c1 >> 2);
     out += ezEncodeChars.charAt(((c1 & 0x3)<< 4) | ((c2 & 0xF0) >> 4));
     out += ezEncodeChars.charAt((c2 & 0xF) << 2);
     out += "=";
     break;
  }
  c3 = str.charCodeAt(i++);
  out += ezEncodeChars.charAt(c1 >> 2);
  out += ezEncodeChars.charAt(((c1 & 0x3)<< 4) | ((c2 & 0xF0) >> 4));
  out += ezEncodeChars.charAt(((c2 & 0xF) << 2) | ((c3 & 0xC0) >> 6));
  out += ezEncodeChars.charAt(c3 & 0x3F);
 }
 document.getElementById('txtPassword').value = out;
  return out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" hint="pass1234" value="pass1234" id="txtPassword"/> 
<input type="button" value="Send" onclick="ezEncode('pass1234')"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**My dart function**

```
 var ezEncodeChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

  ezEncode({String password}) {
    var out, i, len;
    var c1, c2, c3;

    len = password.length;
    i = 0;
    out = "";
    while(i < len)
    {
      c1 = js.charCodeAt(password, i++) & 0xff;
      if(i == len)
      {
        out += js.charAt(ezEncodeChars, c1 >> 2);
        out += js.charAt(ezEncodeChars, (c1 & 0x3) << 4);
        out += "==";
        break;
      }
      c2 = js.charCodeAt(password, i++);
      if(i == len)
      {
        out += js.charAt(ezEncodeChars, c1 >> 2);
        out += js.charAt(ezEncodeChars, ((c1 & 0x3)<< 4) | ((c2 & 0xF0) >> 4));
        out += js.charAt(ezEncodeChars, (c2 & 0xF) << 2);
        out += "=";
        break;
      }
      c3 = js.charCodeAt(password, i++);
      out += js.charAt(ezEncodeChars, c1 >> 2);
      out += js.charAt(ezEncodeChars, ((c1 & 0x3)<< 4) | ((c2 & 0xF0) >> 4));
      out += js.charAt(ezEncodeChars, ((c2 & 0xF) << 2) | ((c3 & 0xC0) >> 6));
      out += js.charAt(ezEncodeChars, c3 & 0x3F);
    }
    print(out);
  }
```

**CONSOLE RUN**

```
  E/flutter ( 4805): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError: Value not in range: 28
    E/flutter ( 4805): #0      _StringBase.substring (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:392:7)
    E/flutter ( 4805): #1      charAt (package:js_shims/src/strings.dart:5:45)
```

Comment: so, what does Dart produce? different output? no output? errors?

Comment: Sorry, he updated my answer, I get an error of that value that is not in the range.

Comment: well, that shows one of 9 possible locations this error has occurred at - any idea which? or how many times the loop has run before you get this error?

Comment: this seems a very complex way to encode a string to base64 ... does dart have any functions to do so? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957427/how-do-i-encode-a-dart-string-in-base64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a word of safety. This password is **not encrypted** using this function. All your javascript function does is a [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encode, a representation of the password string in a different character set. This is fully reversible and not a sufficient password encryption. Actually none at all. You can verify [here](https://www.base64decode.org/) that your "encrypted" password can be decoded to your original password string.

You should read up on how to properly secure and encrypt passwords in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181198/how-to-hash-a-password/10402129#10402129).

If you're still interested in how to convert your string to base64 (**not an encryption**) you can use darts convert package from its core library.

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-convert/dart-convert-library.html

```
import 'dart:convert';

ezEncodeChars(String notAPassword) {
  var bytes = utf8.encode(notAPassword);
  var base64Str = base64.encode(bytes);
  return base64Str;
}
```

Comment: You're right, it's a simple safety word. On my server, when I use the API, the password goes through that security. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript function *charAt* returns an empty string when argument value is out of range. This empty string converts to integer 0. Dart throws an exception that value is not in range. You should handle out of range cases yourself.

Comment: the `charAt` function would never be called with an out-of-range value

Comment: * unless dart's bitwise operators (`>>` `<<` `&` `|`) behave differently, of course