# pass base64 encoded values in api request in POST Api

Tags: flutter, api, dart, yaml

I am new to flutter. how to pass a security key and id in headers and convert the string in the base64 encoded value and send the request to backend?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I encode a Dart string in base64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957427/how-do-i-encode-a-dart-string-in-base64)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15957427/3182210